# Event Manager Not Invoking (Java)

Tags: java, events, methods, reflection

So this is the first time I'm writing a proper event manager but for some reason my method which calls and invokes the stored keys/values throws a NullPointerException even though I added the class and method data to the map in my register method.

My calling method:

```
public static final void fire(final Event event) {
        final Class<? extends Event> clazz = event.getClass();
        final List<EventListener> listeners = eventMap.get(clazz);
        if(listeners != null) {
            for(EventListener listener : listeners) {
                try {
                    listener.getMethod().invoke(listener.getObject(), event);
                } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is where I register/unregister my events:

```
    public static final void register(Object o) {
        Class clazz = o.getClass();
        Method[] methods = clazz.getDeclaredMethods();
        for(Method m : methods) {
            final Handler handler = m.getAnnotation(Handler.class);
            if(handler == null) continue;
            if(!m.isAccessible())
                m.setAccessible(true);
               if(!eventMap.containsKey(clazz) && m.getParameterTypes()[0].equals(clazz)) {
                   eventMap.put(clazz, new LinkedList<EventListener>());
               }
        }
    }

    public static final void unregister(Object o) {
        Class clazz = o.getClass();
        Method[] methods = clazz.getDeclaredMethods();
        for(Method m : methods) {
            if(eventMap.containsKey(clazz)) {
                final List<EventListener> listener = eventMap.get(clazz);
                eventMap.remove(clazz, listener);
            }
        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update: Here's the stacktrace when I remove the != null check.

```js
java.lang.NullPointerException: Unexpected error
 at me.jamie.lib.event.EventManager.fire(EventManager.java:49)
 at me.jamie.revolution.gui.RevolutionUI.func_175180_a(RevolutionUI.java:25)
```

Like I said, the register/unregister methods run without a problem, but when I initiate the fire method it seems to consider the map as empty.

Comment: No stacktrace, no help.

Comment: Where is line 49 of EventManager ?

Comment: for(EventListener listener : listeners) {

Comment: I think the problem must be elsewhere in the code. Have you debugged that register did fill the map before calling fire? Have you debugged that you that the map is not replaced by a fresh one? Or did you unregister an object before calling fire?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you allow only methods which as argument take `o.getClass()` and register them like they would handle them on their own. (Ex. you register class Animal and it handles event Animal only)

```
if(!eventMap.containsKey(clazz) && m.getParameterTypes()[0].equals(clazz)) {
    eventMap.put(clazz, new LinkedList<EventListener>());
}
```

(look at second conditon (register method))

Comment: I was trying to make it so that it only registered classes that had Event as their superclass, but I've removed it and it still considers the map to be empty in my fire method.

Comment: probably because you made your method in a way that event handler must be inside your actual event ...
`eventMap.put(**clazz**, new LinkedList<EventListener>());`
If you want to, then look at mine Fast Event Bus ([link](https://github.com/mibactechnologies/feb))